# How let users to delete their own comments

Tags: 7, nodes, ajax, users, comments

i have installed [Comment Delete](https://www.drupal.org/project/comment_delete) module to change permissions for the user to delete their own comments. If i click the delete link it throws this error.

> You are not authorized to access this page.

Comment: Have you given your user permission on the permissions page?

Comment: yeah.i gave permission to  "Allow user to delete their own comments anytime.
"

Comment: Make sure to clear cache .. Comment Delete module working perfectly. Try it now on https://simplytest.me/project/comment_delete/7.x-1.3 to make sure there is no conflict with your current other installed modules.

Comment: Clear Cache and double check the role of the user if the permissions are perfectly assigned.

Comment: i cleared the cache and checked role of the user also. but still delete not working